# Dangling references in std::function captures. Why undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, reference, functional-programming, shared-ptr, capture

I have a couple c++ programs that both use function captures. One of them succeeds with exit code `0` but the other results in `Segmentation fault` error. The `std::shared_ptr<std::string>()` is captured by reference and should be destroyed before the lambda is called. If this is the case, then why does my first program end in success, but the second one does not?

#### Successful Program

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

std::function<void()> lambda;

void assign_closure() {
  std::shared_ptr<std::string> ptr = std::make_shared<std::string>("nope");
  lambda = [&ptr]() {
    std::cout << "Trying to print this should segault: " << *ptr << std::endl;
  };
}

int main(int, char*[]) {
  assign_closure();
  lambda();
  return 0;
}
```

#### Unsuccessful Program

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

std::function<void()> lambda;

void assign_closure() {
  std::shared_ptr<std::string> ptr = std::make_shared<std::string>("nope");
  lambda = [&ptr]() {
    std::cout << "Trying to print this should segault: " << *ptr << std::endl;
  };
}

void do_some_work() {
  std::cout << "doing some work" << std::endl;
}

int main(int, char*[]) {
  assign_closure();
  do_some_work();
  lambda();
  return 0;
}
```

Is there a compiler flag I can use to spot dangling references?

Comment: The "successful program" is also UB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Undefined behaviour does not mean segfault, it means anything.  "It works" or "format harddrive" or "segfault" or "email your browser history and passwords to all of your contacts".

In this case, the stack and heap had garbage memory that happened to be layed out like non-garbage.

To prevent this, don't use any kind of `[&]` capture unless the lambda and all copies are discarded before the end of the current scope.

There is no way to deterministically detect all dangling references on C++.  Write code in a style that doesn't generate risks of dangling references for 99% of your code.  In the 1% where you cannot for whatever reason, be extremely careful, comment heavily, and include proofs that there are no dangling references.

There are many tools that help track down dangling references, to a greater or lesser extent, but none are reliable enough to deal with programmers insisting on doing dumb things.  Asking for tool recommendations is explicitly off topic on SO.